# Fast way to load all alphabetic characters to a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

For example I have this Hashmap:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Instead of doing `map.put("A",0)`, `map.put("B",0)`... until `map.put("C",0)`, is there any way we can make it fast?

Comment: what do you mean by **make it fast** ? performance wise?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using `map.put("A", 0)`?

Comment: Why `String` and not `Character` as map keys?

Comment: Is this a simplified example? If not, why would you want to do this? Else use an array with indexing convention [char - 'A']

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do it in *for loop*:

```
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) 
  map.put(String.valueOf(ch), 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use double brace initialization. It's very compact and helpful in initializing collections.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
        {
            for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) 
                put(String.valueOf(ch), 0); 
        }
};
```

Note that - put method is called without the map reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
      map.put(Character.toString((char) i), 0);
}
```

Comment: ASCII codes (65 and 90) are quite unreadable (magic numbers); better to use char: for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; ++i) etc

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Can elaborate or give a link to what you mean by magic number in this context?

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao A "magic number" is a fixed number in the source code, without an explaination why this particular number was used. In this example: What is "65"? Why not "66"? Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao: When I say that "65" and "90" are "magic numbers" I mean that it's not evident what do they mean (what's "90"?). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Answer (score 0):

With [io.vavr](http://www.vavr.io/)

```
public HashMap<String,Integer> alphanumericAlphabet() {
    return CharSeq
            .rangeClosed('0','9')
            .appendAll(CharSeq.rangeClosed('a','z'))
            .appendAll(CharSeq.rangeClosed('A','Z'))
            .map(character ->Tuple.of(
                    character.toString(),
                    Character.getNumericValue(character)
            ))
            .collect(HashMap.collector());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IntStream` to add char's to a map:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed((int) 'a', (int) 'z').forEach(ch -> map.put((char) ch, 0));
```